# C++ multiple line input from keyboard

Tags: c++, string, input, cin, getline

For an assignment of mine, we're suppose to take in several lines of input from the keyboard. For example:

Please enter your name:  (this is static. Always 1 input)
Justin

Please enter the names:  (this can be any number of inputs, smallest being 1)
Joe
Bob
John
Jackson

In the end, I want to compare the named entered at the beginning with all of the names entered in after. I tried using getline and cin, but that seems to only work if I know the exact number of names I expect to be entered. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void read_lines( std::istream& in, std::list< std::string >& list ) {
    while( true ) {
        std::string line = "";
        std::getline( in, line );
        if( line != "" ) {
            list.push_back( line );
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have added some rough code showing your efforts on doing the assignment.
However, I will provide you with some initial *naive* code (please read the comments inside!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, temp;
    vector<string> names; // this is just one of the possible container that you can use
    bool result = false; // flag used to store the result of the matching operation (default: false)

    // first we ask the user to enter his/her name
    cout << "Please enter your name:" <<endl;
    cin >> name;

    // then we need something a little bit more complicated to look for variable number of names
    cout << "Please enter the names:" <<endl;
    while(cin)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        names.push_back(temp);
    }

    // This for-loop is used to go through all the input names for good-match with the user name
    for( int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++ )
    {
        temp = names.front();
        if (name == temp) result = true; // change the flag variable only in case of match
    }

    cout << "Valid match: " << (result?"yes":"no"); // ternary operator
}
```

You did not provide in your question enough details.. so the above code may not fully fit your requirements!